pass date values without quotes in postgresql
Is it possible to pass Date value without single quotes in select statements
Query :
select * from Schema_1.table_name where "Date" >=2019-01-01 and "Date"<=2020-12-01

Instead of
select * from Schema_1.table_name where "Date" >='2019-01-01' and "Date"<='2020-12-01'

Thanks in advance

date are string literals why can't you add quote around date ?

No, you must use literal syntax. Why would you want to avoid that? What actual problem are you trying to solve by omitting the quotes?

Looks like you have an issue with SQL injection... Use placeholders like $1, $2, etc.

PostgreSQL provides another way, called “dollar quoting”, to write string constants, example
select $$2024-05-10$$::date;

Check the official documentation, for further info


Is it possible to pass Date value without single quotes

Yes. You can replace them with (named) dollar quotes $$: demo at db<>fiddle
select * from Schema_1.table_name 
where "Date" >= $$2019-01-01$$ --unnamed dollar quotes
  and "Date" <= $$2020-12-01$$;

select * from Schema_1.table_name 
where "Date" >= $here_is_a_date$2019-01-01$here_is_a_date$ --named dollar quotes
  and "Date" <= $here_is_another_date$2020-12-01$here_is_another_date$;

The make_date() function accepts the year, month and day as integers, so you can get away without quotes of any kind:
select * from Schema_1.table_name 
where "Date" >= make_date(2019,1,1)
  and "Date" <= make_date(2020,12,1);

Technically, you could also cast a date-looking integer to ::text first, then to a ::date, if you like being controversial:
select * from Schema_1.table_name 
where "Date" >= 20190101::text::date
  and "Date" <= 20201201::text::date;


I'm included to downvote for the ::text::date suggestion and upvote for make_date…

@Bergi I share that sentiment. A dumb idea that works, remains a dumb idea, plus this just feels wrong. OP gave zero context, so I tossed that in as an actually, technically and if I was somehow allergic to quotes of any kind, I'd make_date() too. Your downvote is more than welcome, as long as it comes 2 minutes after the upvote.
